# Checking if a table exists in BigQuery Java

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to write a function to check whether a table exists or not in BigQuery. The following code always returns true. Where is the problem?

Thanks!

```
    private static boolean checkTableExist() {
    try {
        BigQueryOptions.Builder optionsBuilder = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder();
        BigQuery bigquery = optionsBuilder.build().getService();
        bigquery.getTable(options.getBigQueryDatasetId(), options.getBigQueryTableId());

    } catch (Exception e) {

        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you should rely on java Exception to test a boolean condition.
I haven't looked a lot at the getTable() method, but here is how I check if a table exists:

```
public boolean isExisting() {
    return getDataset().get(tableName) != null;
}

protected Dataset getDataset() {
    return bigQuery.getDataset(dataSetName);
}
```

Comment: Why not  simply call the `exists` method? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigquery/Dataset.java#L174

Comment: Graham, your solution would give me "java.lang.NullPointerException".       `return bigquery.getDataset(options.getBigQueryDatasetId()).get(options.getBigQueryTableId()).exists();`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (bigquery.getDataset(datasetName).get(tableName).exists()) {
  // table exists        
} else {
  // table does not exist in BQ dataset
}
```